# Beginner Python/Pandas Data Analysis - Calculating New Series - Order of Operation?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working on some test data analysis using Python and Pandas. I am very beginner with these languages (good knowledge of Fortran [don't laugh], working knowledge of Java). However, I figured it would be a great opportunity to learn something new.

I have a large csv file with raw data, and I'm trying to calculate new series based on this data. Some of the new series are iterative, meaning they need to use the previous data in order to make that row's calculation. So, I initialize all new series, at the very least to make sure there is data at df[0] for calculations on df[1].

```
data["Re_102"] = 1000.0
data["Re_201"] = 1000.0
data["Cd_102"] = 0.7
data["Cd_201"] = 0.7
...
```

At this point, I use df.interrow() to loop through my data, using df.at to calculate new series data. For the iterative calculations, I use an if statement to check that the loop index is greater than 0, if so, I start making those calculations.

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    data.at[index, "FUEL_TOTAL_SET"] = max(0,row["MFUEL-301-SP"]) + max(0,row["MFUEL-401-SP"]) + max(0,row["MFUEL-501-SP"])
...
    data.at[index, "VISC_AIR"] = 1.48816394 * (1.04125E-21*row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]**5 - 5.06556E-18*row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]**4 + 0.0000000000000092695*row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]**3 - 0.0000000000100597*row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]**2 + 0.0000000185972*row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"] + 0.0000110626)

    if index > 0:
        data.at[index, "Re_102"] = (4.0 * max(0.001,data.loc[index-1, "MASS_FLOW_102"])) / (math.pi * (orifice_d_102/1000) * row["VISC_AIR"] )
        data.at[index, "Cd_102"] = 0.5959+0.0312*math.pow(orifice_beta_102,2.1) - 0.184*orifice_beta_102**8 + (0.09*orifice_beta_102**4)/(orifice_D_102/25.4)*(1-orifice_beta_102**4) - 0.0337*orifice_beta_102**3/(orifice_D_102/25.4) + 91.71*math.pow(orifice_beta_102,2.5)/math.pow(row['Re_102'],0.75)
        data.at[index, "E_102"]  = 1- ((0.41+0.35*orifice_beta_102**4)*(row["DP-102-ORIFICE"]/100000)) / (max(0.1, 1.4*row["PS-102-ORIFICE"]))
        data.at[index, "MASS_FLOW_102"] = max(0,(math.pi / 4)*(orifice_d_102/1000)**2 * row["Cd_102"] * row["E_102"] *math.sqrt( max(0.00001,  (2*(row["PS-102-ORIFICE"]*100000)/(287*(row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]+273.15))*( row["DP-102-ORIFICE"]*1) * 1) / (1-orifice_beta_102**4) ) ) )

    #Other Stuff
    data.at[index, "FP_Burner"]  = row["MASS_FLOW_102"] * math.sqrt(row["TS-AIR-SUPPLY"]+273.15) / row["PS-CMB-INLET"]
    data.at[index, "PHI_Global"] = row["FUEL_TOTAL_ACT"] / (1000*row["MASS_FLOW_102"]) / FAR_stoich if row["MASS_FLOW_102"] else 0
```

I ordered the calculations such that any calculations would have the available data by the time it needs it.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook for this work. I execute this cell, which does the calculations. Then, in the next cell, I have a few debug lines. Executing that, the answers are completely wrong. After screwing around for a while, I realized that ...

If I execute the calculation cell again, the calculations change ... and it seems as if I run that cell 3-4 times, everything seems to calculate more or less correct.

I'm struggling with this. It feels like maybe the code is executing the entire block simultaneously or something ... I can't put my finger on it.

EDIT: On a whim, I started changing all the row variables to the dataframe, such as

```
row["VISC_AIR"] => data.loc[index, "VISC_AIR"]
```

and ... it seems to be working now. I was under the impression that row was a physical slice of the original data frame, but apparently not.

p.s. I'm also struggling a little with Pandas apparent reluctance to want to actually change the data in the frame. It seems it wants to copy or make temporary changes (so we have to use the df.at() function to -inplace=True flags) ... the documentation isn't clear to me this behavior. Any reference here would be appreciated.